# Change-detection not working properly in ng2 component after navigation via angular1 ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, ng-upgrade

In an application that uses ng-upgrade to use some new ng2 (V2.2.4) components inside a big ng1 (V1.5.9) app (using ui-router) I am currently seeing a very strange change-detection issue. As far as I can tell, this has been introduced in some upgrade of ng2, but sadly I can't easily verify that currently.

I have reduced it to a minimal example by now where i simply have this component:

```
@Component({
    selector:'my-ng2-demo',
    template: '<div>{{status}}</div>'
})
export class MyNg2Demo implements OnDestroy {
    public status:boolean = true;
    private interval:any;

    constructor() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.status = !this.status;
            console.log('status: ' + this.status);
        }, 2000);
    }

    ngOnDestroy():void {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

}
```

That component is upgraded in the upgrade-adapter and registered as an entry-component in the module.

The component is used in the template of an ng1 controller like this:

```
<my-ng2-demo></my-ng2-demo>
```

When I open a browser and navigate directly to that page (the route of the ng1 controller) everything works as expected: the ui shows true/false alternating every 2 seconds.

However: when I navigate away & then come back to the page (visiting some different routes) then suddenly change detection doesn't seem to work. The displayed value alternates only about every 5-6 seconds, seems quite random, although in the console I still see the expected values.

When I change the component's constructor to this:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        zone.run(() => {
            this.status = !this.status;
            console.log('status: ' + this.status);
        });
    }, 2000);
}
```

It suddenly works again.

Obviously this isn't a feasible solution since the behavior I'm seeing in the real app is much more complex (i would have to add `zone.run` in dozens of places probably, which would not be maintainable).

I have debugged this for hours and don't understand what is happening.
In Chrome's JavaScript profiler, I basically see that the page idles for almost the whole time in those 5-6 seconds where nothing happens.

[image: profiler]
This is not a screenshot from that demo-component (but it basically looks the same) but from profiling the tab-component I was initially testing (tab-switching took just as long with no visible actions in between).

**update:**

After a bit more experimentation what I find quite surprising also is that when instead of putting the status-changing code into a `zone.run` call, I add a call to `ApplicationRef.tick()`
 (as mentioned here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829089/1335619 ) it also does NOT work at all.
I don't understand why forcing a complete application-change-detection does nothing, but a zone-run call somehow works.

Example code with tick call which does not work:

```
constructor(private applicationRef:ApplicationRef) {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.status = !this.status;
        console.log('status: ' + this.status);
        applicationRef.tick();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal example to reproduce it? Maybe plunker or github repo?

Comment: not yet, but if you know a plunker that already has a basic angular1 + angular2 + ngUpgrade + ui-router setup, i'd be happy to adapt it to my example.

Comment: Check that you do nt have following flag in any component:  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None and try to move logic from constructor to ngOnInit().

Comment: we actually do have encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in one component, but it is a component that isn't even used on each UI, do you still think it can cause it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in the Angular version you are using. Change detection does not work as it should in ng-upgraded apps.

Please refer to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12318 for further details.

If you upgrade to 2.4.4, it should resolve the issue.

Comment: Still bugged for me, version 4.1.1